# How to use a class's method inside a function (PHP)?

Tags: php, oop, function

I'm trying to use the new PHP mysqli extension. I've got a function (safe()) that recursively uses mysql_real_escape_string to make strings safe. How do I use my mysqli connection inside this function to call the mysqli::escape_string() function?

Example:

```
$db = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database_name);


function safe ($data) {
  if(!is_array($data)) {
     if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
       $data = **mysqli::escape_string($data)**
       return $data;
    }
  } else {
    return array_map('safe',$data);
  }
}
```

Where I have **mysqli::escape_string()** inside safe() how do I call that? Outside of a function it would be $db->escape_string() but I can't find a way to call it insde. I've tried passing $db to the function, making $db global etc. The alternative is to use the procedural mysqli_escape_string() but that requires the mysqli link resource to be explicitly passed to it, but I can't find a way to access that.

Comment: You going to mark the right answer?

Answer (score 6):

pass your DB object in to the function.

```
 function safe ($data, $db) {
  if(!is_array($data)) {
     if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
       $data = $db->escape_string($data);
    }
  } else {
    return array_map('safe',$data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would extend the mysqli class:

```
class mysqliA extends mysqli{
    function escape_string($data){
        if(!is_array($data)) {
            if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $data = $this->escape_string($data);
                return $data;
            }
        } else {
            return $this->escape_string($data);
        }
    }
}
```

that way you just have to call

```
$db = new mysqliA();
$db->escape_string($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to encourage you to use globals, but if you wanted to access `$db` from the safe function you would have to put `global $db;` at the beginning of the function.

Resulting in:

```
$db = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database_name);

function safe ($data) {

  global $db;

  if(!is_array($data)) {
     if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
       $data = $db->escape_string($data);
       return $data;
    }
  } else {
    return array_map('safe',$data);
  }
}
```

Please note that globals are considered evil and shouldn't be used.

What should you use then? Well, for your use case the [registry pattern](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/php-patterns-part/)(keep that in mind for later) probably would fit best. But to get you started with object-oriented programming you should try the following for now:

```
class myClass {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database_name);
    }


    function safe ($data) {

      if(!is_array($data)) {
         if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
           $data = $this->db->escape_string($data);
           return $data;
        }
      } else {
        return array_map('safe',$data);
      }
    }
}
```

I urge you to read more about object-oriented programming as it will help you write better and more reusable code.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

if I extend the class I get:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in *file path* on line 22

Fatal error: Call to a member function escape_string() on a non-object in *file path* on line 22
```

line 22 being where the function is

If I pass the mysqli object I get:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for safe() in *file path* on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: db in *file path* on line 22

Fatal error: Call to a member function escape_string() on a non-object in *file path* on line 22
```

My function call is:

```
                    $item[$form] = safe($item[$form],$db);
```

so clearly no missing second var

And I can't build a class around the function and initialise a new mysqli connection (which seems like the height of inefficiency at any rate) becuase I have to make safe() a Static function to make it a valid callback for array_map() and no syntax seems to work for this line:

```
$data = $this->db->escape_string($data);
```

Have tried

```
$data = $this->db->escape_string($data);
$data = self::db::escape_string($data);
$data = self::db->escape_string($data);
```

Comment: Fatal error is because you blindly copied the code, if you look at line 22, it says $db-> instead of $this->

Comment: It should be $db-> because I'm passing an object, not using it within the context of the class itself

Comment: I meant when you are extending the class

Answer (score 0):

Create a public function in your db class file

```
function escape($string)
    {
        return $this->connection->real_escape_string($string);

    }
```

and you can use it like this

```
function safe()

    {
            $id=$this->mysqli->escape($this->id);

            $status=$this->mysqli->escape($this->status);

            $shortcode=$this->mysqli->escape($this->shortcode);



     }
```

the use of function depends upon how you are going to use it